# How to show a popup everytime user login to the app flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-sharedpreference

- I am trying to show a popup saying `Become a member` everytime user login to the app.
- If he logout from the app and login again the pop up should show saying `Become a member`.
- Using `SharedPreference` I am able to do it only once whenever the user login into the app. But I am not able to implement whenever he logout and login again and the popup should come.

Comment: can you share your source code?

Comment: you can do this using shared preferences when user is logged in set value to true  and whenever value is true show the pop up and when user logs out remove the preference value so that when user will  login again it will show pop up again